# CSS Issue with Node.JS / EJS

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I've had a good look through & unfortunately none of the answers are helping me.

My CSS file is being ignored in certain circumstances.

So in my **app.js** file I have this code, defining my view engine setup

```
// view engine setup    
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In my **index.js** file I have the following the code for UserList page

```
/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;                               // (1) Extract the db object we passed to our HTTP request
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');    // (2) Tell our app which collection we want to use
                                                 // (3) Find (query) results are returned to the docs variable
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', { "userlist" : docs });    // (4) Render userlist by passing returend results to said variable
    });
});
```

Finally, my **userlist.ejs** page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User List</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>User List</h1>
    <ul>
      <%
        var list = '';
        for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
          list += '<li><a href="mailto:' + userlist[i].email + '">' + userlist[i].username + '</a></li>';
        }
        return list;
      %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run my page the CSS file is not loaded. However if I exclude this code:

```
<%
        var list = '';
        for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
          list += '<li><a href="mailto:' + userlist[i].email + '">' + userlist[i].username + '</a></li>';
        }
        return list;
%>
```

The CSS file is loaded and applied without issue. Can anyone tell me why this is please? Apologies for the newbie question, but I've been trying to figure this out for ages.

I should mention the 'h1' tags are ignored too. The only thing rendered is the list items.

Not sure if its relevant, but my app is connecting to MongoDB to return the user data.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't cached old (invalid) references? Try `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: 1. Check the HTML your browser has received contains references to your CSS files.  (`CTRL`+`U` to view source).

2. Check the Network Tab of Developer Tools contains requests for your CSS. (`F12` opens developer tools)

3. See if the Developer Tools console gives any reason why your CSS is not rendering. (`Esc` toggles the console in Developer tools).

... any joy?

Comment: Unfortunately there's definitely no old invalid references.
Interestingly the HTML my browser received contains no references to the CSS files. It is completely ignored.
I've reviewed my code again & it definitely looks complete.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your CSS file is either defined as an endpoint in your `index.js` file or make sure that `public/stylesheets/style.css` exists so it can be loaded through the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` command.